# There has to be a better regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a small CMS and I'm trying to turn a title into a URL slug with dashes.  I know I need to do a couple of things and I've got the whole thing work, but I just don't like it.  The problem seems to be that if there are any special characters at the end, I'd need to remove them before it goes into the database.  The only way I could figure out doing this was to do 2 preg_replace's in one statement.  So it looks something like this:

```
preg_replace("/\-$/","",preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', "-", strtolower($title)));
```

and it and turn this: `(this is a title!!!)))**that is (strange))`

into this: `this-is-a-title-that-is-strange`

But this expression just looks like ass.  There has to be a better way of coding this, or something out there, I just don't know it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Note that you might need `/^-+/` to be removed as well for titles that start with invalid characters.  Also, should your first regex be `/-+$/` to remove multiple dashes?

Comment: There might be a way to shrink your commands down to a single function call, but the way you have it now is readable and understandable, and a single-function version is less likely to be those things.

Comment: @Brad: He still needs to lowercase the letters in the string, even with your modification.

Comment: @JeremiahWillcock: indeed. Redacted my comment, I think I'm calling it a night--brain's going on strike.

Comment: @Jermiah you're right about needed that to get rid of "-" in the front but the regex seems to handle something like this hello--world) just fine

Comment: There is this misconception that 1 RegEx is better than 2. The truth is that RegEx is supposed to make your code easier to read and easier to debug. It certainly beats trying to tokenize your strings for customized patterns, but there's no reason to take 2 perfectly understandable RegExs and try to cram them into 1 inscrutable mess. If you need one, you need one, if you need two, use two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make just one call to `preg-replace` with array inputs as:

```
preg_replace( array('/[^a-z0-9]+/','/^-|-$/'), // from array
              array('-',''),                   // to array
              strtolower($title));
```

Note that your existing code retains leading `-` if any. The code above gets rid of that.

Comment: Does that do the replacements for the regexes in sequence?  The second replacement in the from array depends on the first one having already been done.

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: Yes. The replacements happen in sequence. The second one is applied after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

One option, which still requires two replacements but takes care of both the start and end dashes in one pass, is:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '',
  preg_replace('/([a-z0-9])[^a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9])/', '$1-$2',
    strtolower($title)));
```

There is also the alternative of:

```
implode('-',
  preg_split('/[^a-z0-9]/',
             strtolower($title),
             PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim`.

```
trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', "-", strtolower($title)), '-')
```